# when will they meet?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose two runners are 1 km apart and they start running towards each other. Runner A starts running at such a speed that he would run a kilometer in 20 minutes. Runner B starts running at such a speed that he would rum a kilometer in 40 minutes. Importantly, when (if) each of the runners reach half of the track they adopt the speed of their competitor. At what time do they meet?

Comment: So runner $A$ runs for $10$ minutes, then slows to $1 km\over 40 minutes$ pace, while runner $B$ runs for $20$ minutes, then speeds up to $1 km\over 20 minutes$ pace.  However, runner $A$ reaches the midpoint first, so runner $B$ must maintain pace for the duration of the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  A is faster, so how long does it take for him to run the first half kilometer?  Where is B at that time?  How fast are they approaching each other after that?  It would help to draw a graph, with location horizontal and time vertical.  A starts at $(0,0)$, B at $(1,0)$.  The slope of the line is their velocity.

Comment: I get that they will meet after 15 minutes. Is that correct?

Comment: @Adam:  I agree with you.